# Wirecloud failed to run in Firefox / Chrome

Tags: docker-compose, fiware, fiware-wirecloud

I am running dockerized images of wirecloud+nginx from a remote server, trying to access Wirecloud from my browser. Wirecloud failed to load correctly, issueing the following message:

```
Your browser seems to lack some required features
We recommend you to upgrade your browser to the newest version of either Firefox or Google Chrome as these are the browsers currently supported by WireCloud.
```

[image: see image]

I can confirm my browsers (firefox and chrome) are up-to-date, and I can run wirecloud locally on my machine using same browsers, as in [image: image below]

Any idea why this happens please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figure it out now, working...

I had issue with static files environment definitions in my `docker-compose.yml` file that differs for `nginx`and `wirecloud` services.